# Kdocker arbitariily stopped working - docked apps are completley gone

Tags: gnome, gui, docking, top-bar

I use kdocker to minimize a few applications (like Spotify) into the top bar rather than the dash, and it all was working smoothly until a couple of days ago, when suddenly whenever I use kdocker the apps get minimized into oblivion, without an icon showing up at all. The processes are still running in the background and I can communicate with them via terminal.

I have absolutely no idea what caused it, and the problem persists on both X11 and Wayland.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I run 20.4 (Focal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about a day or two, the problem just disappeared, as suddenly and arbitrarily as it came.

Notably, this had nothing to do with a restart, which I tried yesterday multiple times to no avail - but today I just woke up (with the computer still on from yesterday, only suspended) and the problem got fixed.

I'll leave this answer for anyone wondering how to solve the issue (just wait, apparently), but if anyone has this and manages to debug and figure out how to actually solve it, do answer, I'm curious!

EDIT:

Realized I never edited this answer.
Whenever my computer shut down due to battery loss, kdocker would stop displaying top-bar icons until it was completely reinstalled. I have found no way to work around this.